# Store Multiple pcm files in folder on sdcard

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to save pcm file format file to be store in folder and that folder to be saved on SD card. So far I can save only one file of pcm audio file on SD card. I have tried to store more than one pcm files on SD card but then an error occurred. The error was that I didn't record file. Every time I record some sound, file length remain zero kb.

```
 private void startRecord() {



File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/MYfolder/");
        // File file = new File(path,"myrecording.pcm");
        path.mkdirs();
        // file = new File(path, "myrecording.pcm");
        // // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        // // "test.pcm");
        //
        int sampleFreq = 11025; /* (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem(); */

        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile("myrecording", ".pcm", path);
            // recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            // file.createNewFile();
            // File.createTempFile("myrecording", ".pcm", file);

            // OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    audiofile.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    bufferedOutputStream);

            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord
                    .getMinBufferSize(sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            while (recording) {
                int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0,
                        minBufferSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++) {
                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                }
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
    }
    protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
            long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/pcm");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

            Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

            sendStickyBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    newUri));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**i have edited my code, i want to save pcm file on sdcard with in specific folder through content resolver. I am get memory leakage error don't known how to solve that.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOUR_FILE_NAME it should be diffrent every time, use datetime to set file name diffrent

```
private void startRecordinga() {

    AudioRecord  recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}

    //convert short to byte
private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
    int shortArrsize = sData.length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
        bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
        bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
        sData[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;

}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    // Write the output audio in byte



    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath()+"/Myfolder/"+YOUR_FILE_NAME+".pcm";
    short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isRecording) {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
        System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
        try {
            // // writes the data to file from buffer
            // // stores the voice buffer
            byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
            os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    // stops the recording activity
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }
}
```